# Two-way MySQL (db table) replication on live servers

Tags: mysql, synchronize

Is it possible to synchronise specific table of the database on two live server?

With Replication/Cluster mechanism?

Comment: What you are asking for is multi-master replication.  Why do you need to do this / are you sure this is what you need to achieve your goal / what are you trying to achieve?  This article may be worth a read before you get into it too far if you are set on it : http://scale-out-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/if-you-must-deploy-multi-master.html - it may be that an alternative technology / solution is more suitable to your needs.

Comment: Going to host website local in an University's intranet where users spend 60% of the time(with their permission, of course  :P ) .  certain data should be in sync with the public website.

Comment: So why not set up the production website to allow mysql connections from the university ip range thus eliminating that need?  It may require some whitelisting on a firewall or something but realistically it could provide a far simpler solution than trying to maintain 2 databases in sync.  It depends on expected traffic and precisely what the application does, but if structured well the latency shouldn't be particularly noticeable.

Comment: That's because the website serve lots of video content and universities want to serve it locally (as well as public) ..

Comment: Siva, you can still host the website locally, but just leave the database in 1 place and connect to the database remotely.  That way the high-bandwidth videos are local while the relatively low-bandwidth data remains in 1 place thus preventing a sync headache!

Comment: looks cool. Any guides/information about that?

Comment: There's not much to say about it.  You just need to make sure you set up a user i.e. `myRemoteUser@ip.address.goes.here` with the appropriate permissions (SELECT etc.) and then it's just a matter of connecting to the databases IP address instead of `localhost`

Comment: The problem is NOT all the nodes in the Univ. have connection to internet. only one local server has internet.